# Ubuntu installed on a Macbook - no sound, not wake up

Tags: sound, suspend, macbook

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 on a Macbook, it has no sound. I did try to follow several guidance found on AskUbuntu.com but still no sound.

In addition, when the laptop goes into sleep mode, it doesn't wake up. The is a message on the screen "touch any keys" but none of the key stroke could wake it up. I tried all letter keys, number keys, F keys, shift, control, space bar, enter, delete, etc... none of them works.

Would appreciate your help.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkoJI.png)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, it's 20.04. For clarity, a screenshot is added to original post.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. For that particular MacBook, it is ***a lot of work*** to get everything working correctly, and later software updates often break the dirty hacks that are used to resolve the issues with sound and sleep. Unless you really want to learn how to tweak and recompile kernel modules, you may want to use either a VM or a different brand of computer. Apple devices are made for Apple OSes and have often been a challenge for anyone who wanted to run something different.

Comment: Thanks to @matigo for your response. I am not computer savvy hence I would have to keep using it as a limping computer.